# Read ID from SQLite datatable

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to write the colum roomname and after that I want to read the roomid. Therefore Ive got two methods. The first for creating the room and the second for getting the roomId. (After that I want to write this ID in another table)

```
public boolean insertRoomNr(String room){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor dbCursor;

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("roomname", room);
    db.insert(TABLE_ROOM, null, contentValues);

     Log.d("Room Name", room);
    return true;
}

public boolean insertRoomId(String room){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String RoomID;
    RoomID = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_RID + "  FROM " + TABLE_ROOM + " WHERE "+ COL_RNAME + " = ?",new String[]{room}).toString();

    Log.d("RoomID", RoomID);
    return true;
}
```

I call those methods by clicking a button in one of my `Fragments`.

```
    buttonsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Context ctx = getActivity();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mydb.insertRoomNr(roomnr.getText().toString());
            mydb.insertRoomId(roomnr.getText().toString());

            Log.d("ListViewFragment", "RAUMNUMMER HINZUGEFÜGT");
        }
    });
```

The problem is that I get the `Room Name`in my first log. But my `RoomID` log output is `11-11 11:05:33.938 27273-27273/com.sbeyer.daainv D/RaumId: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@f81c8ef` cant I get the ID in plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RoomID = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_RID + "  FROM " + TABLE_ROOM + " WHERE "+ COL_RNAME + " = ?",new String[]{room}).toString();
```

may be use `Like %?%` instead of `= ?`.

check for case sensitivity also.

Comment: There was a additional whitespac e before `FROM` -.- it also works with `= ?`. But my log output is now `11-11 11:05:33.938 27273-27273/com.sbeyer.daainv D/RaumId: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@f81c8ef` cant I get the ID in plain text? or can I add it easier to my other TABLE (as Foreign key)

Comment: The returned is `SqliteCursor` object. use `RowID.getLong(0)` to get the actual value